# Uniform convergence of $ \sum_{{n=1}}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{{ x}}{{n+n^2x^2}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I’ve been trying to prove the uniform convergence of this series the reals using the Weierstrass M-test. I can derive an upper bound of $\frac{1}{n^2}$ for $|x| \geq 1$ but cannot derive the case for the absolute value of $x$ smaller than $1$.

$$
\sum_{{n=1}}^{\infty} \frac{{(-1)^n x}}{{n+n^2x^2}}
$$

Also, I tried another way: writing $f_n(x) = \frac{{(-1)^n \cdot x}}{{n+n^2x^2}}$, I can prove the sequence ${f_n}$ is uniformly convergent and that the limit tends to zero. But I don’t know how to use this result.

Comment: This is even a nice function. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B%28-1%29%5En+x%2F%28n%2Bn%5E2+x%5E2%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2CInfinity%7D%5D

Answer (score 4):

> $$ \sum_{{n=1}}^{\infty} \frac{{(-1)^n \cdot x}}{{n+n^2x^2}} $$

We show it is absolutely  uniformuly convergent

$$ \sum_{{n=1}}^{\infty} \left|\frac{{(-1)^n \cdot x}}{{n+n^2x^2}} \right|= \sum_{{n=1}}^{\infty} \frac{|x|}{{n+n^2|x|^2}}=\sum_{{n=1}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{\frac{n}{|x|}+n^2|x|}}\le \sum_{{n=1}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n^{3/2}} <\infty$$

Note the last step uses $a+b\ge2\sqrt{ab}, ~~\forall a,b\ge 0$